# Connxion failed to mongodb atlas server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I tried to connect to mongodb atlas that i've just created, but I got this error :

> { MongoError: failed to connect to server [mongodbarcode-tt80c.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [MongoError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongodbarcode-tt80c.mongodb.net mongodbarcode-tt80c.mongodb.net:27017]

here's my code :

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import config from '../config/index';

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

const connectToDb = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(mongodb://test:fakepass@mongodbarcode-tt80c.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true, { useMongoClient: true });
       console.log('Connected to mongo!!!');
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
       // logger.error('Could not connect to MongoDB');
    }
}

export default connectToDb;
```

also, i added a whitelist IP address :0.0.0.0/0 to connect from everywhere, but i always get the same error, any suggestions please ?

Comment: Not sure about your actual problem but in your example, the quotes around your mongo-url are missing.

Comment: thanks for  your answer, but this is not the problem, just i forgot to add them,

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought.

Comment: well, Itried to upgrade mongoose and this problem was resolved, but I got a new one :{ Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 3.212.122.122:27017
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1097:14)
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }